# Laravel 4 - How to route subdomain to controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4, wildcard-subdomain

I have a code work with laravel and Wildcard Domain. I like to using Subdomain Route for a controller and I have a route like this:

```
# Tester. URI : www.example.com/tester/{any}
Route::get('/tester/{any}', 'tester@Modules');
```

then i want to using Subdomain routing, so I change the route code like this:

```
#Subdomain route. URL : qwerty.example.com, it same as www.example.com/tester/qwerty
Route::group(array('domain' => '{parameter}.example.com'), function()
{
    Route::any('/tester/{parameter}', 'tester@Modules');
}
```

But didn't work. Can someone help me to resolve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in the domain like `{parameter}.exam...` will be merged with the ones from the route. This causes a naming conflict `{parameter}` and `{parameter}`. You must name the parameters differently:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com'), function()
{
    Route::any('/tester/{parameter}', 'tester@Modules');
}
```

Note that the first argument passed to `Modules()` will be the subdomain and the second the actual route parameter.